# Pandas: Is there an idiomatic way to create rows for each value in a set of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an idiomatic way in pandas to create rows for each value in a set of columns in pandas like below?

```
import pandas as pd

mydf = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': ['A1','A2','A3'], 
        'B': ['B1','B2','B3'], 
        'C': ['C1','C2','C3'], 
        'M1': [1,2,3],
        'M2': [4,5,6]})

def reshape(dataframe, index_columns, index_colname):
    attributes = [c for c in dataframe.columns if c not in index_columns]
    dfs_out = []
    for c in index_columns:
        proj = [a for l in [[c], attributes] for a in l]
        tdf = dataframe[proj]
        proj[0] = index_colname
        tdf.columns = proj
        dfs_out.append(tdf)

    return pd.concat(dfs_out, ignore_index=True)

print(reshape(mydf, ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'I'))
```

Outputs the following:

```
    I  M1  M2
0  A1   1   4
1  A2   2   5
2  A3   3   6
3  B1   1   4
4  B2   2   5
5  B3   3   6
6  C1   1   4
7  C2   2   5
8  C3   3   6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [`pd.lreshape()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L812) to reshape wide-formatted data to a long one wherein it's `groups` keyword parameter accepts a dictionary, like `groups ={new_name:columns_to_combine}`

```
pd.lreshape(mydf, dict(I=list("ABC")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I dont know why is still this method not in docs - maybe some issues?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps, you could get the same functionality by tweaking `melt`. It's been hidden for quite some time now ;-)

Comment: I found it [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/aba7d255a165bbc221be106839c59a876655c0c2/doc/source/release.rst) - `Add experimental lreshape function for reshaping wide to long`

Comment: There's also a similar case with `pd.wide_to_long()`. Both seem to be experimental at this stage.

Comment: It is funny - this notice is for version `0.8.0` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Solution with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), then need remove column `variable`:

```
print (pd.melt(mydf, id_vars=['M1','M2'], value_name='I').drop('variable', axis=1))
   M1  M2   I
0   1   4  A1
1   2   5  A2
2   3   6  A3
3   1   4  B1
4   2   5  B2
5   3   6  B3
6   1   4  C1
7   2   5  C2
8   3   6  C3
```

Comment: I liked this answer too. I ended up using it in my *actual* code (not the code above) because I actually have a use for 'variable' (which can be renamed with the keyword arg `var_name`).